# nodemon instance not found on digital ocean droplet

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, digital-ocean

i deployed my node app on Digital Ocean Droplet.

after installing the dependencies i ran yarn dev

my script:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --delay 10ms --exec babel-node -- app.js"
}
```

after few minutes the ssh connection broke.
i connected again to the ssh, but i am unable to run yarn dev script again, as the previous nodeman is still running on port 3000.
how to get a instance of nodeman and stop it so that i could run it new instance.

Answer (score 0):

did some more research...

To find the nodemon process, use:

```
sudo netstat -plten |grep node
```

This should list all currently running node processes and their PIDs. Find the correct PID and then kill it with

```
kill [PID goes here]
```